# Laravel 5.2 Auth not persisting on other routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel. The Laravel app I am creating works perfectly on my local machine, but when I uploaded it on my host the Auth session is not persisting on other routes.

**routes.php**

```
Route::group([], function () {
        Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.domain.com'], function() {
                 Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@login');
                 Route::get('/checklogin', 'CheckLoginController@check');
        });
});
```

**LoginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User as User;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function login()
    {
        $user = User::find(1);
        Auth::login($user);
        return "logged in"; //returns logged in
    }   
}
```

**CheckLoginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;

class CheckLoginController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function check()
    {
        if( !Auth::guest() ) :
            echo "logged in";
        else :
            echo "Not logged in"; //returns this
        endif;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Did you also insert an user with the id 1 ? what are the settings for your session driver? is your storage writeable? What laravel version exactly do you use-  do you need the middleware wrap ( 5.2.3.4 + ) ?

Comment: @FrankProvost I am use "File" for my session driver. Yes my storage is writeable. Laravel version 5.2.44. Yes user with id of 1 exists on my database

Comment: Since Laravel Version 5.2.31+ you do not need to add the web middleware group in your routes. It might occur that you have it doubled now which might cause that problem. Try to remove it from your routes and ensure it exists in your RouteServiceProvider where it should be appended to every route in the file routes.php. You can read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel-5.2/4285/change-default-routing-behaviour-in-laravel-5-2-31#t=201608300816174709667

Comment: @FrankProvost Yes I removed the wrap but still the same problem. :(

Comment: What exactly is the problem which behaviour do you have? Which behaviour do you want?

Comment: @FrankProvost if you can see on LoginController I logged in a user with an ID of 1. And it returns "logged in". Now when I try to access the route /checklogin I get "Not logged in". Supposedly I should be logged in on all other routes. On my local machine it works like that, but when I uploaded it to my host it doesn't persist anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122178/discussion-between-frank-provost-and-clyde-scope).